# PHP split csv line into multidimensional array

Tags: php, csv, multidimensional-array, php-5.4

I am looking for a way to split a csv line into the keys of a multidimensional php array

a,b,c becomes

```
$some_array['a']['b']['c'] = true;
```

a,b,d,e becomes

```
$some_array['a']['b']['d']['e'] = true;
```

Comment: What happens if you have a,b,c,d followed by a,b,c? You will first set `$some_array['a']['b']['c']['d'] = true;` which means `$some_array['a']['b']['c']` is an array. But then you will set `$some_array['a']['b']['c']` to be boolean true - overwriting the contents of the first line. You will need to make sure all rows in your CSV have a fixed number of columns for your question to make sense.

Comment: @Annabel good point. In this case the data is ordered so that this wont be an issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe something like this?

```
<?php
$csv_inputstring =
"1,2,3
a,b,c
d,e,f";
$output = array();
foreach(explode("\n",$csv_inputstring) as $line){
   $values = str_getcsv($line);
   $tmp = &$output;
   foreach($values as $value){
      if (!is_array($tmp)){
          $tmp = array();
      }
      $tmp = &$tmp[$value];
   }
   $tmp = true;
}

print_r($output);

?>
```

The result for this test:

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [2] => Array
                (
                    [3] => 1
                )

        )

    [a] => Array
        (
            [b] => Array
                (
                    [c] => 1
                )

        )

    [d] => Array
        (
            [e] => Array
                (
                    [f] => 1
                )

        )

)
```